# How to fix empty objects returned by Giraffe API fetched from DB through SqlDataProvider

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-giraffe

I am trying to learn F# by creating an F# application with a repository to fetch Exercises for a future Gym-application.

I use SqlServer to store the data and am fetching the data using Fsharp.Data.Sql. The unit tests for this work well.

I am trying to expose the data through a web api using Giraffe, the problem is that i get back a list with the correct length but with empty objects inside.

Here is the context:

```
module Context

open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER
let [<Literal>] connectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-20JMHNK;Database=GymStrongDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000
let [<Literal>] useOptTypes  = true
let [<Literal>] owner = "public, admin, references"

type sql =
    SqlDataProvider<
        dbVendor,
        connectionString,
        "",
        "",
        indivAmount,
        useOptTypes,
        owner>

let gymStrongContext = sql.GetDataContext()
```

Here is the Repository

```
namespace GymStrong.Repositories

open ...

module ExerciseRepository =
    let ctx = gymStrongContext.Dbo

    let getExercises = 
        ctx.Exercises |> Seq.toList

    let getExercisesHandler : HttpHandler =
        fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->
            Successful.OK getExercises next ctx
```

And here is the relevant part from Program.fs

```
open ...

let webApp =
    choose [
        GET >=> 
            choose [
                route "/" >=> text "Hello World"
                route "/user" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> getLoggedInUser
                route "/logout" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> logoutHandler
                route "/exercises" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> getExercisesHandler
                ]
        POST >=> 
            choose [
                route "/register" >=> registerHandler
                route "/login" >=> loginHandler
            ]
    ]
```

In the unit-tests, this works properly. The unit tests are written in C#.

When i consume the API through PostMan i get this response

```
[{},{}]
```

Which has the correct length since i have two exercises in the database, but the objects seem empty.

Comment: Your underlying question is "how can I test a complex program", and the answer is: by making it less complex, or more minimal. Your program does two things: extracts data from a source, and communicates it over the web. To find which is the culprit, you can eliminate the data extraction part by altering the relevant function to return fixed data. You will then be able to remove either "Giraffe API" or "SqlDataProvider" from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful to someone, so i will post it.

Both Giraffe and SqlDataProvider are doing what they should. The problem was that i thought that i could pass the provided type as a json-response in the API. That is wrong since the provided types are not real types and are "erased" (instead of Generated which is the type that i thought i was working with).

In order to fix this, i needed to map out the values to a "real" anemic DTO object and pass it as a response. Now i need to figure out if one can provide these anemic DTO-objects based on the entityTypes and have them be generated and usable from other assemblies.

Additional code:

In the repository/service

```
    type exerciseDto = { 
        Id : string;
        Name : string;
        Description : string;
        Owner : string;
        Type : int; 
    }

    let getExercises = 
        ctx.Exercises |> Seq.map(fun exercise -> exercise.MapTo<exerciseDto>()) |> Seq.toList
```

And in program.cs

```
let handlerWrapper action : HttpHandler =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctxHttp : HttpContext) ->
        Successful.OK action next ctxHttp

let webApp =
    choose [
        GET >=> 
            choose [
                route "/" >=> text "Hello World"
                route "/user" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> getLoggedInUser
                route "/logout" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> logoutHandler
                route "/exercises" >=> mustBeLoggedIn >=> handlerWrapper getExercises
                ]
        POST >=> 
            choose [
                route "/register" >=> registerHandler
                route "/login" >=> loginHandler
            ]
    ]
```

Hope this helps anyone save time in the future. It took me at least a few hours.

Comment: Do you mean program.cs?